# android MediaPlayer Orientation

Tags: android, media-player

I'm editing an app and am in charge of video playback. I'm using android.media.MediaPlayer for the playback. The trouble I'm having is this. The app's manifest specifies a portrait layout. I need the video playback to be in landscape. I cannot however just simply change the orientation as too much of the rest of the app relies upon it being portrait. So to my question.
Is it possible to force the video to play in landscape using MediaPlayer regardless of the orientation of the app. And if not, what would be the best alternative API to MediaPlayer that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution was to override the onConfigurationChanged event, like so:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: on click full screen is working how to but how to landscape when click  button

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your media player in a separate activity and specify its own orientation in the manifest. That might be not the only/best way to go, but it surely works.

Comment: Yeah, had considered this but there's too much else going on in the current activity, and there'd be too much interaction between the two activities for this to really be viable. Thanks though.
I'm now exploring the Animation route to see if that helps, but am concerned about the lag effects this will have on the video